# When to use a button input or a hyperlink styled as a button?

Tags: html, css

I have a small welcome screen on a website which asks users to either log-in or sign-up. Pretty standard stuff.

The log-in button is within a form so it is a `<input type="submit">` element.

However the Sign-up button is not within a form. Its purpose is just to send people to another page where they can register. But I want this this button to look the same as the button that says "log-in" for consistency/aesthetics.

What would be best-practice for the Sign-up link I want to achieve:

1. Use a `<input type="button">` element within a form that takes the user to register
2. Use a standard hyperlink but style it in CSS so that it looks like a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's semantically a link, but styled as a button, use an `<a>` element with CSS to make it look like a button.

Comment: what tag would you wrap the hyperlink in? its not a paragraph or a heading or even a list.

Comment: @volumeone, why would you need to wrap the hyperlink?

Comment: In my CSS I need to add a margin to it. The element above this hyperlink is a H2 tag. In my CSS I tried h2+a {margin-top:15px;} but it doesn't work. If I wrap the hyperlink in a H3 for example and do this h2+h3 {margin-top:15px;} then it works.

Comment: @volumeone, by default, `a` elements are inline, which means that top and bottom margins and padding don't affect them. Try adding `display: inline-block` to the `a` styles.